# How do i render a html file in grails that has source files included in the html?

Tags: javascript, grails

I have a project in grails where I'm doing the UI part in a separate grails independent project. I'm calling the html file in the UI project from the grails controller in a different project.

How do I render the html files from the controller? Currently, I'm using the render command to convert the *htmlContent* into text format and rendering the text. But I released I cant include relative source tags inside that html and I'll need to hardcode it in the html.

```
render text: htmlContent, contentType:"text/html", encoding:"UTF-8"
```

Any other effective way to render the html (from a different project) from the grails controller?

Answer (score 0):

The following is the problem as I understand it:

1. You have a Grails project containing a controller.
2. You have Grails plugin project containing the UI (html, css, etc).
3. The *controller* project is configured in grails-app/conf/Build.groovy to depend on the *UI* plugin.
4. You want to render the UI in the *UI* plugin project from the controller in the *controller* project.

Views are rendered exactly the same way regardless of whether they are contained in the same project or not. For example, if the *UI* project has a view at *grails-app/views/ui/index.gsp*, then the controller in the *controller* project can render it like this:

```
render(view: '/ui/index')
```

I don't know where your *htmlContent* is coming from, but usually rendering text is for very simple things, such as JSON; not for HTML which may contain other resources (like images and CSS files).

See, in Grails the URLs to [static resources](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.4.4/guide/theWebLayer.html#resources), such as images and CSS files, are **generated** by either the Resources or Asset-Pipeline plugins. Either way, trying to set the path to such resources directly in HTML code will not work.

If you convert you *htmlContent* into a GSP page and use either the Resources or Asset-Pipeline, then you'll be able to render HTML content with sources.

Check *grails-app/conf/Build.groovy* for the line *compile ":asset-pipeline:x.x.x"* in the plugins section. If it's there, heck just go with the [Asset-Pipeline](http://bertramdev.github.io/asset-pipeline/guide/usage.html#linking)! It's the new way to manage static resources.

Comment: actually, we are doing the UI part without using grails. We are using only knockout js without using any groovy tags. hence the use of html.

so basically the UI project only contains, .html and .js files to work with! Its a simple project and not a grails project.

Comment: that external UI project need not necessarily be part of the grails framework! it could be done even on eclipse or something! we just configure the path of that UI project in the environment variables and setting up that path in the Config.groovy file in grails....

grails.project.UI.name = System.getenv("UI_HOME")

Comment: Ok, so it sounds like you have a single-page application with Grails for the back-end. If you _really_ want to keep both projects independent, then I recommend implementing a REST API in Grails and leave the rest (no pun intended) to a web server such as Apache. The Grails controllers would render XML or JSON rather than HTML and sources would work as expected. To use Grails as the web and application server you'll need to use GSP. Here's a decent overview of how to implement a [SPA in Grails](http://www.slideshare.net/alvarosanchezmariscal/singlepage-applications-and-grails)

Comment: SPA!! You just opened me up to what i was exactly looking for but didn't know existed! Thank you!!